# Use a model trained on image to detect objects in videos?

Tags: google-cloud-automl, google-cloud-vertex-ai

Using Google Vertex AI, I trained a model to detect some specific objects in images.

Can i use this trained model to detect sames objects, but in videos ?

Answer (score 0):

The following  requirements apply to datasets used to train AutoML or custom-trained models;

- Vertex AI supports the following video formats for training your model or requesting a prediction (annotating a video).

  - .MOV
  - .MPEG4
  - .MP4
  - .AVI
- To view the video content in the web console or to annotate a video, the video must be in a format that your browser natively supports. Since not all browsers handle .MOV or .AVI content natively, the recommendation is to use either the .MPEG4 or .MP4 video format.
- Maximum file size is 50GB (up to 3 hours in duration). Individual video files with malformed or empty timestamps in the container are not supported.
- The maximum number of labels in each dataset is currently limited to 1,000.
- You may assign "ML_USE" labels to the videos in the import files. At training time, you may choose to use those labels to split the videos and their corresponding annotations into "training" or "test" sets.

For best practices  on video data used to train your models, you can see [this](https://cloud.google.com/vertex-ai/docs/datasets/prepare-video#best_practices_for_video_data_used_to_train_models)  link.